# RxJava2 that acts like AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

Hi I just start learning Reactive programming using RxJava2.
How do I create a task that runs in the background thread and then complete on main thread using RxJava2.

Example in Android we use AsyncTask just like example below

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>
{
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... paths)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < paths.length; index++)
        {
            boolean result = copyFileToExternal(paths[index]);

            if (result == true)
            {
                // update UI
                publishProgress(index);
            }
            else
            {
                // stop the background process
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
    {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        int count = values[0];
        // this will update my textview to show the number of files copied
        myTextView.setText("Total files: " + count);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result)
        {
            // display a success dialog
            ShowSuccessAlertDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            // display a fail dialog
            ShowFailAlertDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

For this example I want to pass in a Array / ArrayList of Strings and it is use to execute some method in the ***background thread***. Then every success result will update my **TextView (UI thread)**. If one of the process fail, I want it to stop directly. Lastly I want to update my **Views** when the process has completed.

I only manage to get this far

```
Observable.just(paths).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<ArrayList<String>>()
            {
                private boolean result;

                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d)
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ArrayList<String> paths)
                {
                    for (int index = 0; index < paths.size(); index++)
                    {
                        result = copyFileToExternal(paths[index]);

                        if (result == true)
                        {
                            // cant update UI because is in background thread
                            myTextView.setText("Total files: " + index);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // end the loop
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e)
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete()
                {
                    if (result)
                    {
                        // cant display because it is still in background thread
                        ShowSuccessAlertDialog();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // cant display because it is still in background thread
                        ShowFailAlertDialog();
                    }
                }
            });
```

I looked at a few tutorials but can't seem to find the answer.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Why would you?  If you want an AsyncTask, use an AsyncTask.  Even if its possible using an RxJava observable of some point, there's no benefit to doing it that way over an AsyncTask other than trendiness.  Remember if its taking you this must difficulty to figure out how to do it, it will take a maintainer at LEAST this much effort to figure out what you were doing.

Comment: I would say because of the employers. Many things are achievable with AsyncTask or writing your own Threads. However due to the rising popularity of Reactive Programming. Those employers requires software engineers to have the skills and knowing to use RxJava library is much more convincing to them. So I'm trying to learn to solve this question at its simplest form.

Comment: And as a senior engineer, if I saw you writing this with rx java, you wouldn't get the job. It's quite simply the wrong tool.  There's things the library is the right tool for, learn those instead.

Comment: I don't agree @GabeSechan. Using RxJava in place of AsynTask has a lot of advantages, in particular it is easier to deal with memory leaks, it is also much concise, it has a simpler way for handling errors, and most important RxJava is much more flexible: It allows you to compose more streams together or to exploit parallel execution. I think almost nobody is using `AsyncTask` anymore.

Comment: @Gvillani82 if you think nobody is using AsyncTask anymore, you're completely wrong. The number of people using it over rx java is an order of magnitude- rx is trendy, but it's single digit percents of android apps at most. It also has just as many memory leak issues if you don't know what you're doing. It's just the newest hipster programming trend

Comment: I said almost nobody @GabeSechan, but to be honest I don't know any professional Android developer that still use `AsyncTask`. The memory leak is not the only reason: I wrote a list of motivations in my comment and you react just against one. Some people at Google use RxJava as well: RxJava is part of the Google source tree.

Comment: @Gvillani82 and I know almost 0 who use rx java, especially not for a use case like this. Those who do are the bad ones, it isn't the right tool. There are places it is (my current app uses it for notification of changes to loosely bound compile time uis), but not here. Not everything is a nail. Do you have any idea of the amount of objects and complexity you add to your program by doing it this way? If you're doing this, you're writing bad code

Comment: @GabeSechan I have quite a lot of experience in RxJava, and I know when to use it. This is the case. Expecially if you want to make it flexible enough to compose it later with some other stream (for example)

Comment: @GVillani82 So do I.  This is absolutely not.  It's interface is more complex than other solutions, its less efficient, less understandable by the average developer.  Using it here is the wrong tool for the job.  Look at the fact his half working solution is *more complex* codewise than just using an async task, and it isn't even working yet as it hasn't solved the problem of sending results back to the ui thread.

Comment: Ok, good for you @GabeSechan

Comment: Just in case you missed it @GabeSechan Google just introduced support for `Flowable` in the Room framework for observing the database changes. It seems a clear direction about how important is becoming RxJava in Android.

Comment: @GVillani82 Google can do whatever they want-  its still a bad solution to base your app around, unless you have very special circustances.  It is still not a replacement for an AsyncTask, and anyone using it as one is incompetent.

Comment: @GabeSechan Then Daniel Law (GDE) from Trello is an incompetent. In his article he said "I originally wrote this article when I was (foolishly) still using AsyncTasks [...] My preferred alternative these days are combining RxJava with schedulers. You get the same effect as an AsyncTask with none of the  problems, plus you get an awesome framework in addition. I know, recommending a library to solve a problem is irritating, but RxJava is worth looking at for many reasons." [here the article](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/06/21/the-hidden-pitfalls-of-asynctask/). Take a look at all the advantages.

Comment: @GVillani82 Then he's incompetent.  There's lots of people at a lot of places who are incompetent.  Many of them have blogs.  Also, reading that article-  he didn't mention a single reason why rxJava was better, just reasons why AsyncTaks have issues.  So if he's arguing for that he's also an incompetent writer.  The only thing that article would be gopod for is as an argument against Android's "recreate on rotation" behavior, which I'll totally agree with him on-  its one of the worst design decisions I've ever had to deal with.

Comment: @GabeSechan Are you serious? [Dan Law](https://twitter.com/danlew42) doesn't just has a blog. He is a great speaker of Android conferences all over the world and also he is a [Google Developer Expert](http://blog.trello.com/google-developer-expert). Take a look on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=daniel+lew+android). I learned a lot from his talks. I think he is far away from being an incompetent.

Comment: @GVillani82  No clue who he is, nor do I really care.  Here's a hint for your future arguments:  appeal to authority is a logical fallacy.

Comment: @GVillani82 In addition its a rather poor article.  Don't use AsynTasks because you can only queue 130ish?  If you're doing that to begin with you're doing something wrong.  His section about canceling is not only obvious to anyone who read the API, but its basic multithreading knowledge-  you can't safely cancel a Thread from outside the Thread itself.  This is either filler because he felt he had to keep to a blog schedule, or he really is not that good if he believes there's actual insights here in a 2014 blog post. (Edit: ok, original posted 2011, more resptable but still trivial)

Comment: @GabeSechan I was just proving you that you were wrong about the incompetence of everyone uses RxJava in place of AsyncTask. That's it. And also that article explains in more details why it makes sense.

Comment: @GVillani82  But it doesn't.  RxJava isn't even mentioned.  No reasons to use it instead are given.  Its like saying you need to buy a swimming pool because here's reasons why my bike is broken.  He gives no reasons how rxJava solves his problems, how it avoids the other problems ( rotation is still an issue with rxJava, and can even be worse), or any of the tradeoffs involved.  How can you say it explains why it make sense when it provides 0 arguments or evidence?

Comment: @GabeSechan maybe you are right. I mean, I am sure you have good reasons for saying what you are saying. In my experience, I have found using RxJava a good advantage in my projects. I believe also that it probably doesn't always make sense to use RxJava in place of AsyncTask. (but it makes more sense, for example, when you can immagine your data as a stream, so that you can combine it with other streams).
Anyway, the thing is: I think you are wrong about "who does it is an incompetent.". You are too stiff, in my opinion. It is never all black or white. Good luck.

Comment: Even if you are a senior engineer that doesn't meet you know what you are talking about too. That is a state name you gave yourself and some people around you.  Please people don't trust the first comment from a "senior" you see as a true one.

Comment: I would not hire a senior if he doesnt know what reactive or functional programming is and I would fire him right away. I suggest to all that would try to use AsyncTask in 2017 for the wrong reason. To please do it inside their prototype apps and not in a professional application. There is a reason  why the world is going up and trying to improve. And technology with it if you are an idiot and cannot go up and learn even if you are a senior then you are not for the right place.

Comment: I found it really strange that some people that cannot go with the flow. Try to convince other people to stay behind and blind them on the way so others can stay at the bottom with them. Please read as much as possible. Test and you will see which one is better for the usage you need. If you don't do it you will never know which one is best for the situation.

Comment: They finally made it [official](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/base/+/1156409/6/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java#49). So, indeed @Izvorski, this is the price that we have to pay if we don't go with the flow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
Observable.fromArray(getPaths())
    .map(path -> copyFileToExternal(path))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(aInteger -> Log.i("test", "update UI"),
               throwable -> ShowFailAlertDialog),
               () -> ShowSuccessAlertDialog());
```

A good idea is usually to have a "handler" for controlling the subscription to your observer. So that, when you need to stop your background task (for example because the user left the Activity), you can use it. For this purpose you can use `subscribeWith` instead of `subscribe`, that receive as input a `ResourceObserver`: in this way you get a `Disposable`.

```
Disposable subscription = Observable.fromArray(getPaths())
    .map(path -> copyFileToExternal(path))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeWith(new ResourceObserver<Integer>() {
         @Override
         public void onNext(@NonNull Integer index) {
             Log.i("test", "update UI");
         }
         @Override
         public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
             ShowFailAlertDialog();
         }
         @Override
         public void onComplete() {
             ShowSuccessAlertDialog();
         }
   });
```

When you need to stop the task you can just call:

```
subscription.dispose();
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day...I just realize subscribe(new Observer<>) was the problem..subscribeWith solves it

Answer (score 1):

I'm new at this, but I got a working example..

```
//Observable
Observable.just("input_parameter")
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())//creation of secondary thread
            .map(new Function<String, String>() {//<input obj,return obj>
                @Override
                public String apply(String cad){//input obj
                    Log.d(TAG,"thread :"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    //runs in a secondary thread
                    return "result text: "+doLongNetworkOperation();
                }
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(MyObserver);//now this runs in main thread
```

And MyObserver:

```
//Observer
Observer MyObserver = new Observer() {
    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onSubscribe thread:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Object value) {
        Log.d(TAG,"on next, valor:<<"+value.toString()+">> \n nombre hilo:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Log.d(TAG,"error "+e.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        Log.d(TAG,"onCompleted thread:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
};
```

Plz, let me know if this works for you.